# how prevent repetition inside action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

when i traced the execution i saw something weird

when i press  page number it will call action but there is repetitions 3 times inside action that means not go to view after finish action just go up again
the problem is by pressing pagination because when i use other way there is no repetition
this is View Page

```
@model IPagedList<Tested1.Models.SupportTicketsDetails>
```

@using PagedList.Mvc;

@using PagedList;

@{
ViewBag.Title = "View_All_SupportTickets_tab2";

```
Layout = null;
```

}

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("View_All_SupportTickets", "etraining", FormMethod.Get))
{


  

    @Html.TextBox("searchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new {  @placeholder = "اكتب هنا للبحث" , @class = "inputbox"} )



    <button type="button" onclick="searchFun()" class="btn btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search "></i></button>



}

<br />


<table class="table">
    <tr>

        @*
            <th>
                @Ajax.ActionLink("Web Order ID", "_CustomerWebOrders", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.IdSortParm }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "partialCustomerWebOrders" })
            </th>

            <th>
                @Ajax.ActionLink("Ship To Name", "_CustomerWebOrders", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "partialCustomerWebOrders" })
            </th>*@

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Support_Tecket_Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Created_Date)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Order_by)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Technical_problem_name)
        </th>
        @*
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Created_details)
            </th>*@
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Location)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Technician)
        </th>
        @*
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Current_Technician_Id)
            </th>*@
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Status)
        </th>
        @*
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Last_replaier_Id)
            </th>*@
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Last_replier)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Last_reply_Date)
        </th>
        @*
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TestValue)
            </th>*@
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @if (Model == null)
    {
        <h2> No Records Found !</h2>
    }
    else
    {

        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Support_Tecket_Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Created_Date)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Order_by)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Technical_problem_name)
                </td>
                @*
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Created_details)
                    </td>*@
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Technician)
                </td>
                @*
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Current_Technician_Id)
                    </td>*@
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
                </td>
                @*
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Last_replaier_Id)
                    </td>*@
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Last_replier)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Last_reply_Date)
                </td>
                @*
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TestValue)
                    </td>*@
                
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("عرض", "EditSupportTicket", new { id = item.Support_Tecket_Id }) 
            
            </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }


</table>



@if (Model != null)
{


    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("View_All_SupportTickets_tab2", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, page }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new PagedListRenderOptions() { DisplayLinkToPreviousPage = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded, DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = false, DisplayItemSliceAndTotal = false, MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay = 10 }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "partialAllOrders", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
}
```

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")


<script type="text/javascript">



    function searchFun() {
       
        var search = $('.inputbox').val();
       
       
        $.ajax({
            url: "/etraining/View_All_SupportTickets_tab2",

            data: { searchString: search },
            cache: false,
            type: "get",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (result) {

                $("#partialAllOrders").empty().append(result);

                
                $("#tab2").tab('show');
            }


        });



    }
```

this is action

```
        public PartialViewResult View_All_SupportTickets_tab2(string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)


    {





        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }




        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);


        ViewBag.currentFilter = searchString;





        var query2 = (from st in Db.Support_Teckets
                     join tr in Db.trainers on st.trainer_id equals tr.trainer_id
                     where tr.trainer_name.StartsWith(searchString) || searchString == null






                     join pr in Db.Technical_problem on st.Technical_problem_Id equals pr.Technical_problem_Id

                     join x in

                     from rp in Db.Ticket_Reply.GroupBy(m =>
                     m.Support_Tecket_Id).Select(m => m.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault())

                     join tr in Db.trainers on rp.trainer_id equals tr.trainer_id



                     select new { rp, tr }


       on st.Support_Tecket_Id equals x.rp.Support_Tecket_Id into g

                     from gx in g.DefaultIfEmpty()



                     select new SupportTicketsDetails
                     {
                         Support_Tecket_Id = st.Support_Tecket_Id,
                         Created_Date = st.Created_Date,
                         //Created_Time = st.Created_Time,
                         Order_by = Db.trainers.Where(b => b.trainer_id == st.trainer_id).FirstOrDefault().trainer_name,

                         Technical_problem_name = pr.Technical_problem_name,
                         Created_details = st.Created_details,
                         Location = st.Location,

                         Technician = Db.trainers.Where(b => b.trainer_id == st.Current_Technician_Id).FirstOrDefault().trainer_name,
                         Status = string.IsNullOrEmpty(gx.rp.Status) ? "بلاغ جديد" : gx.rp.Status,

                         //Closing_Date = st.Closing_Date ,

                         Last_replier = Db.trainers.FirstOrDefault(a => a.trainer_id == gx.rp.trainer_id).trainer_name.ToString(),


                         Last_reply_Date = gx.rp.Date,

                         //Last_reply_Time = gx.rp.Time,


                         //points = st.points



                     }).

                         OrderByDescending(a => a.Created_Date).ToList().ToPagedList(pageNumber, 6);







        ViewBag.CurrentSort = "tab2";

        return PartialView("View_All_SupportTickets_tab2", query2);
```

thanks for your assistance

regards

Comment: what is another way?

Comment: By press search button

Comment: Resolved......?

Comment: I still work on that page 3 days till now :(

Comment: I resolved problem but when I am on 2nd tab and press search button show me sersult but 1st tab is active